# Create hive table by using spark sql

Tags: apache-spark, hadoop, hive, pyspark

I'm trying to create a hive table with parquet file format after reading the data frame by using spark-sql .Table has been created in hive with Sequence file Format instead of parquet file format.But in the table path I could see parquet file was created.I'm not able to query this one from hive.This is the 
code I have used.

```
df.write.option("path","/user/hive/warehouse/test/normal").format("parquet").mode("Overwrite").saveAsTable("test.people")
```

I'm using spark 2.3 and hive 2.3.3 along with MapR Distribution

show create table people:

```
ROW FORMAT SERDE
  'org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.lazy.LazySimpleSerDe'
WITH SERDEPROPERTIES (
  'path'='maprfs:///user/hive/warehouse/test.db/people')
STORED AS INPUTFORMAT
  'org.apache.hadoop.mapred.SequenceFileInputFormat'
OUTPUTFORMAT
  'org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.HiveSequenceFileOutputFormat'
```

Comment: Please drop table from hive then run your spark code. Or alter table properties, See https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+DDL#LanguageManualDDL-AlterTableProperties

Answer (score 1):

LazySimpleSerDe is for CSV, TSV, and Custom-Delimited Files

```
ROW FORMAT SERDE
  'org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.lazy.LazySimpleSerDe'
WITH SERDEPROPERTIES (
  'path'='maprfs:///user/hive/warehouse/test.db/people')
STORED AS INPUTFORMAT
  'org.apache.hadoop.mapred.SequenceFileInputFormat'
OUTPUTFORMAT
  'org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.HiveSequenceFileOutputFormat'
```

for parquet  you have to use different serde or have to specify stored as parquet.

```
STORED AS PARQUET
LOCATION ''
tblproperties ("parquet.compress"="SNAPPY");
```

Since you're using spark, if hive table is already exist then it will not touch meta data info only updated data. Technically it is not going to drop and recreate the table. It will create table only if table doesn't exist.